# How to Load External JS and URL in Joomla Protostar Template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, joomla

I am looking to add a hamburger menu to my joomla protostar template similar to the one found on the following URL:

```
['https://codepen.io/PaulVanO/pen/GgGeyE']
```

This will allow me to have a fullscreen hamburger menu for my desktop and mobile screen. The problem I am having is that within the files from the above link there are 3 links, 2 to external JS files and 1 CSS file and I am not sure how I can write this into a Protostar Template. The following are the three links:

```
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/animate.min.css'>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/0.1.12/wow.min.js'></script>
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>
```

I would really appreciate it if somebody could advise on how I can add the above scripts to my file in order for me to build this within Joomla.

Currently I am using Joomla version 3.8.2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get it to work?

Comment: musashii, i did manage to add it, but the menu button does not animate so not sure what it is, but a different issue i'm guessing.

Comment: The site can be found at: [http://s116169771.websitehome.co.uk/joomla_hamb_menu/], seems like an issue with my js code as the menu does not open...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example from the [manual](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page)

```
<?php
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript('/media/system/js/sample.js');
$document->addStyleSheet("/joomla/components/com_mycustomcomponent/css/mytooltip.css",'text/css',"screen");
?>
```

Comment: Thanks musashii, will have a look and let you know how i get on.